# How to find button inside of table row in protractor js?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

> I am using protractor js for testing. Here i want to click on delete button which inside of table row but when i try to find by id i am unable to find it.

Code:

```
it('should delete the batch successfully when admin is logged in', function(){
  element(by.repeater('batch in batches.list').row(0)).element(by.id('delete')).click(); 
  ptor.sleep(500);
  ptor.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
}
```

Error:

```
    1) Batch modal should delete the batch successfully when admin is logged in
   Message:
     Error: No element found using locator: by.repeater(batch in batches.list").row("0")"
```

How can i make it work. Could anyone provide suggestions?

Comment: I have followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594306/clicking-on-a-in-a-ng-repeat-table-protractor-e2e-test-angular but it is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to click a button in row in a table using protractor js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113686/how-to-click-a-button-in-row-in-a-table-using-protractor-js)

Comment: yeah. i have followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594306/clicking-on-a-in-a-ng-repeat-table-protractor-e2e-test-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am not sending delay so what happen i am checking for the button which is not loaded
ptor.sleep(500); fixes my problem. It took so much time to identify